# Where do I get a list of all default IMAPS of the imaps.vim plugin?

Tags: vim, mapping

The `imaps.vim` documentation mentions examples like this one

> As an example, when you type `EFI` in `|insert-mode|`, you will get the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{\psfig{figure=<+eps file+>}}
\caption{<+caption text+>}
\label{fig:<+label+>}
\end{figure}<++>
```

Where do I get a list of all the siblings of `EFI`? What are all the other mappings?

Comment: imaps.vim? I assume you mean this http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=244. Where did you find the quoted line/documentation?

Comment: @ldigas, right here: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html#place-holders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in `:help latex-suite`, in Section 3.1 Environment Mappings

[image: Environment Mappings]

Answer (score 2):

```
:verbose imap
```

will output a list of all the *INSERT* mode mappings available in Vim and tell you where they are set.

But it seems that the plugin actually uses a custom `IMAP()` function instead of regular `imap` or `inoremap`. I'm not sure the above command will be of any help.

I see a bunch of these custom mappings in [`ftplugin/latex-suite/bibtex.vim`](http://vim-latex.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=vim-latex/vim-latex;a=blob;f=ftplugin/latex-suite/bibtex.vim;h=2cc819957993393751f6ca4ee226bd352768184a;hb=HEAD#l127), there are probably many more scattered around the `ftplugin` directory.

I would do something like `:vimgrep IMAP *.vim<CR>` in `ftplugin` then `:copen` to access all occurences.

Comment: Be careful with wording. `verbose map` won’t ever list *all* keyboard mappings, it will list only normal, visual and operator-pending ones, while it is obvious from the name of the function that TS needs insert-mode ones.

Comment: Thanks ZyX, I've amended my answer with `:verbose imap` which shows insert mode mappings.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to vimgrep you can analyze source code of IMAP() function. It is a small function and from its code you can see that it saves information into script-local variables and the ones with right sides of mappings are `s:Map_.*`, while ones left sides are `s:LHS_*`. So you should do

```
" Arguments do not matter, all you need is to start a debugger 
" with appropriate context
debug call IMAP(0,0,0)
" step into IMAP function
s
" Generate and show a table filetype - list of mapping LHSs
echo "Ft\tLHSs\n".join(map(items(filter(copy(s:), 'v:key[:3] is# "LHS_"')), 'v:val[0][4:(stridx(v:val[0], "_", 4)-1)]."\t".join(split(v:val[1], "\\\\|"))'), "\n")
" Interrupt function so that it won’t do anything
q
" Note that in debugger “q” command is doing an interrupt, not quits vim.
```